# Changing a variable in another class without a static variable?

Tags: java, getter-setter, static-variables

in the program that I am writing at the moment, I have 2 JFrames (each in a different class, each has a different purpose, however you could consider the widget frame to be a slave of some sort), one is a main window, and the other is a 'widget' that pops up upon hitting a button in the main window. 
I only want one copy of the widget open at one time. I am currently doing this through boolean variables under an actionPerformed action listener. Below is the action listener for the main window.

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                   if(getOpenWidget() == false){ 
                       System.out.println(getOpenWidget()); //test line
                       widget.initialize(); // please note that the instance "widget" is declared just after "public class MainWindow{"  :)
                       widget.frame.setVisible(true);
                       setOpenWidget(true);
                       System.out.println(getOpenWidget() ); // test line

                   }else{
                       System.out.println(getOpenWidget());
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "There is already an instance of the Booking Widget open.");
                   }
               }
```

Now the booking widget is open, on the booking widget there is a cancel button. Below here is the action listener for the widget's 'cancel' button.

```
    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            MainWindow ui = new MainWindow();
            frame.dispose();
            ui.setOpenWidget(false);
        }
    }
```

Now, upon hitting my button in the main window again, in theory, the openWidget bool should be false, and allow me to open another window, however in the cancel button action listener, my variable isnt changed. So, am I going about my problem in the right way without making openWidget a static variable?(I should be using getters and setters right?) 
What am I doing wrong and what don't I understand about instantiating a new instance of the main window every time I click that button?

Also, my getters and setters are stock standard as follows.

```
void setOpenWidget(boolean val){
    this.openWidget = val;
}

boolean getOpenWidget(){
    return this.openWidget;
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce the sheer volume of code and text in this question and come up with a more straightforward and clear question?

Comment: put your complete code for the class containing `cancel` action and button

Comment: err, you have a difference instance of your `MainWindow` class in the cancel button action listener......

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the reference of MainWindow to the Widget class so that it can update its flag on cancel button.

Comment: I don't quite understand how I would do this, could you provide a quick example please? - I have an instance of MainWindow, I'm not sure how to do a reference.

Comment: Pass the instance of MainWindow to the constructor of the widget class and store it in its instance variable. And refer to it in the action listener of your cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setOpenWidget(false)` on some other new instance you have created using this line `MainWindow ui = new MainWindow();`

You should call `setOpenWidget(false)` using same instance from which you have initialised widget. Pass the reference of MainWindow to widget while creating widget and invoke `setOpenWidget(false)` using that reference

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the object of `widget` within `MainWindow` you can call it like this:

```
widget = new Widget(this);
```

And change the Widget Window Constructor as follows:

```
MainWindow ui;
public Widget(MainWindow mw) 
{
  this.ui = mw;
  //...initialize btnCancel...
  btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            frame.dispose();
            ui.setOpenWidget(false);
        }
    });
  //..do all other stuffs here...
}
```